# Java memory: Object consumes thrice the size it should

Tags: java, string, memory, csv

Consider a class with a static factory method, which gets a CSV (or TSV) line as input (Variable names renamed for convenience):

```java
String[] fields=StringUtils.split(tsvLine, '\t');
return new MYObject(
    Integer.parseInt(fields[0]),
    StringUtils.strip(fields[1], "\"").intern(), // Many duplicates
    StringUtils.strip(fields[2], "\""),          // Unique
    StringUtils.strip(fields[4], "\"").intern(), // Many duplicates
    Double.parseDouble(fields[7]),
    Double.parseDouble(fields[6]));
```

This method parses around 5 million records, from a file ~500 MB in size. In order to save memory, I save the three Strings concatenated:

I've tried the following optimization:

```java
public MyObject(int i1, String str0, String str1, String str2, 
                double d1, double d2)
{
...
this.tsvStrings = (str0+'\t'+str1+'\t'+str2).toCharArray();
...
}
```

(These are split, of course, in the appropriate getters and setters).

The process size is still well over 1GB, although most of its contents is ignored. What's the best way to optimize this? Am I keeping unnecessary references?

**EDIT**: str0 and str2 have duplicates, str1 is unique.

Comment: So you hold 5M MyObject in memory ?

Comment: Yes, in a HashMap that maps id to MyObject.

Comment: How much is garbage and how much is actual data?

Comment: Out of interest, how have you determine what size the objects *should* be, such that they're three times that size?

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle As a rule of thumb, I took the original file size as the reference size. Note that I take only 5 fields out of 12 from each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a file which is encoded with UTF-8, it will use about double that in memory by default (as it uses UTF-16 in memory).  That is because String and StringBuilder uses two bytes per character (for most characters)

If you manipulate that data, you can need double or more that amount of memory.

You can make the processing more compact using memory mapped files, and plain bytes etc, but given 16 GB of memory costs about £100 it may be a better use of your time to use more memory.

Comment: -1 for UTF-8. Java internally uses UTF-16: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp#text-representation
+1 for insightful comment on cost of physical memory vs programmers' time :)

Comment: @JohnnyBeGood The first line wouldn't make any sense if you replaced UTF-8 with UTF-16. I can only assume you mis-read it. I have added a comment to make it extra clear. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you have. I tried many optimizations like using char[] arrays instead of Strings and so on. Finally I stopped using Strings and arrays almost everywhere. Instead, I created simple cache of words:

```
com.google.common.collect.BiMap<Integer, String> stringCache = ... 
//you can use 2 java.util.HashMaps instead
```

This approach decreased memory utilization and significantly improved speed of my application. You can't go better than this :)

Of course this solution might not be useful for you e.g. when number of unique words in your data to total number of words is close to 1.

If you don't like this solution just buy more RAM as Peter Lawrey says. All other approaches are just partial solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As others before me have said, you could use some kind of compression scheme to save on memory (look into maybe doing a Huffman Code scheme or something similar), although this can get complicated very quickly - it may not be worth the coding effort if this isn't production-level code.

Another thing you could do with much quicker results depends on if the text you are reading is Unicode or ASCII.  Unicode takes 16 bits for each character, and `char` variables in Java take up 16 bits each because of that fact.  However, if your text file is stored using ASCII or if you know that the file doesn't contain any characters not supported by ASCII, you could cast each `char` read into a `byte` and use `byte[]` instead of `char[]`.  This can potentially eliminate up to half of your current memory usage.